# MySQL query returns no data (var_dump = NULL), why?

Tags: php, mysql

I've spent too many hours on this simple enough problem that I cannot understand what in the world is happening for it to be returning do data whatsoever, when I use `var_dump` on the function it returns `NULL`. To be exact, it returns "No results" as I have set it to that if there aren't any data to be retrieved, only that the database is full of data, but it isn't retrieving, can anyone see the issue where I cannot..I've even tried here earlier but nothing.

Here is the function..

```
public function search()
{
    if(isset($_GET['search']))
    {
        $searchTerms = trim(strip_tags($_GET['search']));

        $sth = $this->db->prepare(
            "SELECT COUNT(*) 
               FROM articles 
              WHERE (article_content LIKE :search1) 
                 OR (article_title LIKE :search2)"
        );

        $sth->execute( 
            array(
                ':search1' => '%' . $searchTerms . '%', 
                ':search2' => '%' . $searchTerms . '%'
            ) 
        );

        if($sth->fetchColumn() > 0)
        {
            while($row = $sth->fetchAll())
            {
                return "search results: ".$row['article_title'];
                return "".$row['article_content'];
            }
        } else {
            echo "No results!";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are doing `SELECT COUNT(*) `, then you will never be able to show `$row['article_title']` or `$row['article_content']` as `COUNT(*)` != `article_title` or `article_content`

Comment: @Sean, thanks but I edited and still equaled "No results", removed the count and column fetch.

Comment: Try using `if($sth->rowCount() > 0)` instead of `if($sth->fetchColumn() > 0)`

Comment: If only, frustrating thing --'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use alias in your SQL to this:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare(
            "SELECT COUNT(*) AS RESULT_COUNT
               FROM articles 
              WHERE (article_content LIKE :search1) 
                 OR (article_title LIKE :search2)"
        );
```

And get the count using `$row['RESULT_COUNT']`

Then create a separate query for the results like:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare(
            "SELECT article_title, article_content
               FROM articles 
              WHERE (article_content LIKE :search1) 
                 OR (article_title LIKE :search2)"
        );
```

On the other hand, understanding what you want to achieve, you can fetch the `article_title` and `article_content` using the 2nd query alone and then get the count using:

```
if($sth->rowCount() > 0)
```